# Allow "Special Characters" in C language on Windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, character-encoding, windows-console

If I execute this code (compiled with command
`gcc accents.c -o accents && cls && accents`)
on Linux DEB (like Debian or Ubuntu), all works fine.

If I execute this code on Windows 10, it no detect Special Characters.

How I can allow special characters (Like "Àlex", that À) to work fine code on Windows?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void NetejaBuffer(){ while(getchar() != '\n'); }

int comparaCadena(char p1[],char p2[]){
    int i=0;
    while (p1[i]!='\0'){
            if (p1[i]!=p2[i]) return 0;
            i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main (){
    char Paraula1[30]="Àlex"; // Define Main Word: Àlex
    char Paraula2[30]; // Define variable for Second Word
    int i=0; // Define no go to the next step beafoure writte Main Word
    while (i==0){
            printf(" Main Word:  "); // Show text "Main Word" on terminal
            scanf("%[^\n]",Paraula2);       // Ask a word. It will save on "Paraula2" variable
            NetejaBuffer();

            if(comparaCadena(Paraula1,Paraula2)) {
                    printf(" NICE! \n "); // If word are the same on Main Word, show text "NICE!"
                    i=1; // And define variable i as 1
            }else printf("TRY AGAIN! \n "); // If word are no the same, show text "TRY AGAIN!"

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code naively compares bytes from a string literal, with who knows what encoding, with bytes read from the console, again with who knows what encoding -- if the console's input code page even includes "À".

Comment: Use UTF-8 for the source file, and, if compiled with Visual C++ (cl.exe), use the compiler option `/utf-8`. I haven't used gcc (MinGW) in a long time, so I don't know how it determines the source file encoding for string literals.

Comment: As to console I/O, the console doesn't properly support setting the input codepage to UTF-8 (65001), not even in Windows 10. It's buggy. Non-ASCII characters are read as null bytes. If you need to support Unicode in the console, one option is to switch stdin to UTF-16LE mode via `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT)`. You'll probably want to do the same for stdout. Then switch to using `wscanf` and `wprintf` with wide-character (`wchar_t`) strings. Again, this assumes your're using Visual C++ (cl.exe).  I don't know about gcc (MinGW, MSYS2) when it comes to console I/O.

Comment: Which character encoding is the compiler emitting (`/execution-charset` or equiv)? (If the source character encoding isn't made to match between editor and compiler, then there is no reason to even run the program.)

Answer (score -1):

À is not a special character.If you observe the ASCII values you will find this character
get through this link 
https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-a-grave-accent-lowercase-ascii-code-133.html

Comment: Is not possible allow that characters with a command of similar?

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is defined for values 0 to 127. 133 definitely is not ASCII!

Comment: Your referenced webpage is very unclear as to which "Extended ASCII" character set they are describing. In any case, the only character set and encoding that matter are the ones that the asker is using, which wasn't stated.